# HTML5 - Saving canvas background along with image

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a site that allows cropping and saving image from a canvas.

My current code is able to display the cropped image in the canvas, but I'm trying to save the background of the canvas as an overlay on top of the cropped image as well.

```
crop = function(){
    //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
    var crop_canvas,
        left = $('.overlay').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
        top =  $('.overlay').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
        width = $('.overlay').width(),
        height = $('.overlay').height();

    crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    crop_canvas.width = width;
    crop_canvas.height = height;

    crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

    window.open(crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

  }
```

Link to sample image cropping code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGKeQQ

In this case, I'm trying to save the iPhone image from `.overlay` background on top of the cropped image.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, this part is not clear `I'm trying to save the background of the canvas as an overlay on top of the cropped image as well` , could you provide more details?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan Based on the sample, I have an image set as the background for `.overlay` class in the css, which is `background: url(http://www.tayo.fr/images/iphone5-png.png) no-repeat;` with a z-index of 999 so it stays on top of the image I am cropping. When the image is cropped using the code from the sample, only the image in the overlay is shown (woman), but not the background (iPhone). I would like to save the cropped image along with the background as well (in this case, the iPhone on top of the woman's photo)